# Маркеры для изменения размера Canvas в WPF приложении

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-canvas

Имеется приложение с размещенным Canvas в нем, необходимо задать маркеры на краях Canvas, чтобы при захвате и перемещении маркера можно было изменить размеры самого Canvas. 
Не могу придумать, как нарисовать эти маркеры на границах Canvas.

XAML

```
<Grid Background="DarkGray" DockPanel.Dock="Left">

     <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

         <ItemsControl
               Name="GeneralItemsControl"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Background="Beige"
               ItemsSource="{Binding Shapes}">
               <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <Canvas
                                Name="GeneralCanvas"
                                Width="300"
                                Height="250"
                                Background="White"
                                IsItemsHost="True"
                                MouseLeftButtonDown="OnMouseLeftButtonDown"
                                MouseLeftButtonUp="OnMouseLeftButtonUp"
                                MouseMove="OnMouseMove" />

                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style>
                            <!--  а это привязка координат контейнера к VM  -->
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Position.X}" />
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Position.Y}" />
                        </Style>
                 </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
          </ItemsControl>


     </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Наверное, это канвас и маркеры для него должны быть помещены в другой канвас

Comment: @АндрейNOP то же так думаю но ItemsControl не позволяет использовать больше одного элемента

Comment: При чем тут ItemsControl? Либо помещайте его самого в Canvas, либо делайте это внутри ItemsPanelTemplate. Я рекомендую вам для начала избавиться от всего лишнего, сделать простую разметку из канваса и маркеров/элементов внутри него. Реализовать свою задумку на таком простом макете, а потом уже запихивать всё это в ItemsControl или куда хотите.

Comment: воспользуйтесь стандартным [GridSplitter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.gridsplitter(v=vs.110).aspx):  
`Canvas` помещаем в ячейку `Grid`, в узких соседних ячейках сверху/снизу/слева/справа размещаем по одному `GridSplitter`, причём у тех, что должны работать по горизонтали выставляем `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"`, а у вертикальных соответственно `VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`.

Answer (score 2):

Давайте я проиллюстрирую, что имел в виду @Alias в своём комментарии.

Вы вместо `Canvas`'а используете такую конструкцию:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="100" Width="10"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  ResizeDirection="Columns"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="100" Width="10"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  ResizeDirection="Columns"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="10" Width="100"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  ResizeDirection="Rows"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="10" Width="100"
                  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  ResizeDirection="Rows"/>

    <Canvas Background="LightGray" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10"/>
</Grid>
```

Получается:

[image: неуверенное перемещение]