# Подвижный контрол

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите, а как в WPF можно сделать подвижный контрол? Ну скажем, в контейнере есть какая-то кнопка и я хочу дать возможность менять ее размеры и двигать.

Что-то гуглил и нашел решения через прямую работу с событиями, хотя, в WPF вроде как советуют использовать MVVM.

Comment: Ну, если используешь MVVM, то нужные параметры(положение, размер) так же привязываешь и делаешь с ними что нужно.

Comment: А всякие маусэнтеры и ливы и кей пресс дауны?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/804413/218063

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/508647/218063

Comment: Вторая ссылка — наверное, дубликат?

Comment: @VladD, ну там нету про то как менять размеры